# Ruby- NoMethodError in ReviewsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFCf9.png)

Attempting to call the reviews for the currently signed in user so that on that specific view page, it populates to show all the reviews for that current user. I also tried `reviews = current_user.reviews` and its still not working. I'm fairly new to rails. Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yKJc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. It is fairly simple but will save lot of time.

I am still giving you direction.

Change your `index` action as below

```rb
def index
  @reviews = current_user.reviews
end
```

now in your `index.html.erb`, iterate `@reviews` to render it's detail. Checkout https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-articles

Answer (score 0):

I've found the easiest way to play around with 'what should work', is to experiment in the console.

I'd check these things:

1. That records in the reviews table have a user_id column.

Look in the schema.rb for the reviews table and check it has a user_id column, if it's not there the next step is to add a column to the table via a rails migratation.

2. That the User model and the Reviews model are linked.

app/models/review.rb should contain:

```
belongs_to :user
```

app/models/user.rb should contain:

```
has_many :reviews
```

3. Now play with it in the rails console..

Open your terminal.
Open the rails console:

```
bundle exec rails console
```

I usually use a little shorthand in the terminal naming my variables with a single letter just for speed.

For example maybe start by looking at the last User.

```
>  u = User.last  
>  u.reviews   # see if it works here, much easier to debug and try again
```

Make a new user and add to them..

```
>  v = User.new(name: "Bob", password: "blah", password_confirmation: "blah")
>  r = Review.new( user: v, ... set other fields as needed.. ) 
>  v.reviews
```

Hopefully they help you move along